# Why are my color pdfs not saving as grayscale when I am specifying grayscale?

Tags: python, pdf, save, jpeg, wand

I am using code that is not throwing errors but it is not behaving as expected.  I expect this code to save the pdf as grayscale images.  It does save the images but they are still in color.
I know they are not in grayscale because I'm using numpy to convert them to pixel tabels (list of lists) and they contain the 
[[255,255,255][255,255,255]]... structure of a color image.

```
from wand.image import Image as Img

   with Img(filename=pdf_file, resolution=300) as img:
      img.type = 'grayscale'
      img.compression_quality = 99
      img.save(filename=image_file)
```

I am opening the files with PIL using .convert('L').  I think I'm opening them as grayscale but that doesn't seem to be solving my problem either.

```
   img = Image.open(first_page).convert('L')
```

Comment: Try calling `img.transfrom_colorspace('gray')`.